# collection of category and subcategories?

Tags: php, laravel

category table

```
id| name               | parent_id   
--|------------------  |-----------  
1 | Clothing           |  null   
2 | Shirt              |  1   
3 | Sports shirt       |  2   
4 | Men's sports shirt |  3   
5 | Hat                |  1
```

Category Model:

```
    public function child()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
    }

    public function newRelation($allCategories){
        if ($this->child->isNotEmpty()) {
            $children = collect();
            $allCategories = $this->subCategories($children);
        }
        return $allCategories->unique();
    }

    public function subCategories($allCategories) {
        $this->child->map(function($item, $key) use(&$allCategories){
            $allCategories->push($item);
            if ($item->child->isNotEmpty()) {
                $allCategories->push($item->subCategories($allCategories));
            }
        });
        return $allCategories;
    }
```

controller:

```
$allCategories = collect();
$category = Category::find(1);
$result = $category->newRelation($allCategories);
```

some how it works but returning some extra data collection in another collection , actually in subCategories method every time return $allCategories including the whole collection and eventually the result have collection including itself.
Any idea?

Comment: could you elaborate -"it works but returning some extra data collection in another collection and I want it simply" makes no sense. What extra data? What do you expect?

Comment: actually in subCategories method it returns $allCategories that has result at the end its repeated over and over in the loop

Comment: I've added an answer which should hopefully solve your issue, you just need to adjust it to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the guidance somewhat worked but finally I used a useful package  [lazychaser /
laravel-nestedset][1]

that makes it so easier to work with category and subcategories

```
$categories = Category::with('descendants')->get()->toTree();
```

or just

```
$categories = Category::with('descendants')->get()->toFlatTree();
```

also you can put the ancestors instead of descendants
its so easy
[1]: https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest moving logic into relevant classes to make it easier to understand what you are doing.

- controller:

```
    public function get(Category $category): Collection
    {
       return (new GetAllCategories($category))->handle();
    }
```

- model

```
    public function children(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
    }
```

- GetAllCategories action class. This class will loop through each child and return relevant children.

```
    public function handle(): Collection
    {  
        return $this->buildCategory($this->category);
    }

    protected function buildCategory(Category $category): Collection
    {  
        return collect([
            'category' => $category,
            'children' => $this->getChildren($category),
        ]);
    }   

    protected function getChildren(Category $category): Collection
    {  
        return $category
                ->children
                ->map(fn($child) => $this->buildCategory($child));
    }
```

I didn't add `use` statements, `__consturct` methods or route bindings. I assume that you are using php7.4 and laravel 7.*